# Is there a way to reduce the weight of a certain attribute/variable in XGBoost?

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio, xgboost, mlr

I'm using the mlr package and trying to build an XGBoost model in R studio on the following dataset:

```
return          age        diff_in_days     item_odds     picky_users
0             50.75877          5             -14           -3
0             50.75877         NA             -42           -3
1             49.74507          5              1             3
0             49.74507          5              16            3
1             49.74507          5             -31            3
1             49.74507          5             -27            3
0             49.74507          5             -30            3
```

I'm trying to predict whether a customer will return an item or not based on the other 4 variables. My model is doing good with no overfitting until I include the picky_users variable.

picky_users is an engineered feature that counts how many returns vs non-returns per user ID, so you might have figured out that my model overfits heavily when tested on new data. However, I don't want to exclude the variable entirely, because I think it can improve my predictions.

My problem is that XGBoost puts too much weight on that variable, so I would like to know if there is a way to reduce it manually by tweaking the model. Here is my code:

```
>task <- makeClassifTask(data = train, target = "return", positive = "1")
>xgb.learner <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob",
                           par.vals = list("verbose" = 0,
                                           "early_stopping_rounds"=10))

xgb.parms <- makeParamSet(
    makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5),
    makeNumericParam("lambda", lower = -1, upper = 20),
    makeNumericParam("lambda_bias",  lower = 0, upper = 200),
    makeNumericParam("alpha", lower = -1, upper = 10),
    makeIntegerParam("nrounds", lower=80, upper=700),
    makeIntegerParam("max_depth", lower= 1, upper= 6),
    makeNumericParam("gamma", lower = 0, upper = 10),
    makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree", lower=0, upper = 1),
    makeDiscreteParam("min_child_weight", values = 1),
    makeNumericParam("subsample", lower=0, upper=1))

>tuneControl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit=100, tune.threshold = FALSE)
>rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method = "RepCV", rep = 2, folds=3, stratify = TRUE) 
>xgb.tuning <- tuneParams(xgb.learner, task = task, resampling = rdesc,
                         par.set = xgb.parms, control = tuneControl, measures = mlr::auc)
```

I'm doing a private Kaggle competition, so I do not know if the new data includes some of the same user IDs. Is there a possibility that my model should not overfit and that the predictions drop because the new data has entirely different user IDs?

I'm not an expert, so any tips to improve my code and do not answer the question directly are also welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you want to go away from *machine* learning :) I would engineer the feature that's giving you trouble differently. AFAIK there's no way to manually tweak an xgboost model.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you.